# how to get country list in dropdownlist in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-select

I am working on a project and in the registration page I want to get a list
 of all countries in a dropdown list. Can anyone please show me what I
 need to do in the Controller, the View or whatever is required ? I have a view of the
registraion page

```
@model Retail_MVC.Models.registration
@{

    Layout = null;
}

<div class="my_wrapper">
         <div class="my_left_box">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username)
         </div>
         <div class="my_right_box">
           <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="UserName"/>         
         </div>

   </div>
  -- here i want to get dropdownlist for all countries
```

Comment: Could you please show us the model that you're passing to this view (registration) ? Do you include a list of countries in it ?

Comment: no , not include.. i want to get countrylist from google Api, or from any new way..

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of very useful helpers that come as default with the ASP.NET MVC framework, but one that always seems to get people confused is the Html.DropDownListFor() helper method. So in this post, I’ll quickly go over the steps I use to populate the list, as well as some of the more funky features once it’s up and running!

In our example, there will simply be a single drop down list on a form that shows a list of countries, from which you can select and submit.

First, we need to build a view model that is going to be the contract that determines the data that the view can display.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    // Stores the selected value from the drop down box.
    [Required]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    // Contains the list of countries.
    public SelectList Countries { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel();
        viewModel.Countries = new SelectList(GetCountries(), "ID", "Name");
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.Countries = new SelectList(GetCountries(), "ID", "Name");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        { return View(viewModel); }

        //TODO: Do something with the selected country...
        CMSService.UpdateCurrentLocation(viewModel.CountryID);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, Model.Countries)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryID, Model.Countries, "- please select -")

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")"
  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/selectmenu.css")" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/selectmenu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('select').selectmenu();
</script>
```

Comment: which namespace are require for this in controller?

Comment: what is GetCountries().. is it inbuilt method? i dont want to get list from database.. i want to get list from google Api or whatever online source....

Answer (score 3):

use [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Globalization.CultureInfo%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

```
// Namespaces You need
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

// GetCountries() method
IEnumerable<string> GetCountries()
{
     return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                       .Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID).EnglishName)
                       .Distinct()
                       .OrderBy(x => x);
}
```

**EDITS**
**//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

```
class Country
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
{
    return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
         .Select(x => new Country
                         {
                             ID = new RegionInfo(x.LCID).Name,
                             Name = new RegionInfo(x.LCID).EnglishName
                         })
                         .GroupBy(c => c.ID)
                         .Select(c => c.First())
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

Comment: thanks dear from this function i get list of countries but i want to get id and value .. for that what i have to do in controller

Comment: @AbhijitPandya, see my edits, if I correctly understood what You need.

Comment: dear friend, i get what i need but it get list of only 127 countries. i need list for all countries in world is 244..

Comment: This doesn't always give you the English name.

Comment: additional: you can use http://peric.github.io/GetCountries/ as data source

Answer (score 1):

Try Some thing like below... it will help you...

**In HTML View :**

```
@{
    var CountryItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    CountryItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = String.Empty, Value = String.Empty });
    foreach (var name in ViewBag.Names)
    {
        CountryItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = name, Value = name });
    }
}

@Html.DropDownList("dropDownList", CountryItems)
```

**In Controller :**

```
List<string> countries =new List<string>(2);
var dtList = from ctry in objContext.Details
    select ctry;   // Source of Country
foreach (var dt in dtList)
{
    countries.Add(dt.Name);
}
ViewBag.Names = countries ;
return View(dtList);
```

Comment: "what is objContext.Details".. i cant get it.. any namespace require for it?

Comment: objContext.Details: objContext -is a object and Details - is a collection object like dictionary

Answer (score 0):

In your registration model, add a list of type countries - obviously this will change depending on what youy country datatype looks like

```
public List<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
```

Then in your controller, assign your countries to it from whatever data source you've chosen

```
registration.Countries = [list_of_country_objects]
```

And finally your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("countries", new SelectList(Model.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer dear.. i know this syntax but mainly i need source in controller that from where i get this list like google Api or whatever and how, i can add statically but in database i want to store id?

Comment: I don't know if a list is available from google - that's not really what you asked IMHO. Given that the list won't change very often, why don't you create a table of static data, i did a quick search & found [a list of countries and ISO codes](http://www.textfixer.com/resources/dropdowns/country-dropdown-iso-html.txt)

Comment: Is [this](http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=demo) the sort of thing you mean?